# How to set up redirect in docusarus via plugin @docusaurus/plugin-client-redirects

Tags: docusaurus

In my docusarus page I'd like to set up a redirect:

1. from `example.com/docs` and `example.com/changelog`
2. to `example.com/docs/intro/` and `example.com/docs/changelog/` respectively

I installed the plugin @docusaurus/plugin-client-redirects and I created the following entry

```
      [
        '@docusaurus/plugin-client-redirects',
        {
          redirects: [
            // /docs/oldDoc -> /docs/newDoc
            {
              to: '/docs/',
              from: '/docs/intro/',
            },
            {
              to: '/changelog/',
              from: '/docs/changelog/',
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
```

But I still get `Page not found`.